# How can I update an entity where $id is NOT autogenerated in Doctrine (Symfony 4)?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

My Symfony 4 entity has a non-autoincrement ID:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PropertyRepository")
 */
class Property
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    .....

    public function setId($id): self
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }
```

I use the `setId()` method to set it myself.

```
$prop = new Property();
$prop->setId(1);
$prop->setName('baobao');
$this->em->persist($dbProperty);
$this->em->flush();
```

I've no problem on INSERT, but if I run the same code twice if fails:

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

The second query is an INSERT too, even if I was expecting an UPDATE.

Comment: You can't add an entity with the same id twice. If you want to update an entity that already exist, you have to get it from the db first. Then Doctrine will be aware of the existence of the entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Florian Hermann comment pointed m in the right direction. As show here https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#updating-an-object it's required to load the object first:

```
$propertyRepository = $this->em->getRepository(Property::class);

$dbProperty = $propertyRepository->find($id);

if(empty($dbProperty)) {

    $dbProperty = new Property();

} else {

    $dbProperty->setId($id);
}


$dbProperty->set....
$dbProperty->set....
$dbProperty->set...
$this->em->persist($dbProperty);

$this->em->flush();
```

Comment: You're welcome. But maybe set the id manually is not the best idea.

Comment: @FlorianHermanngenerally I would strongly agree, but here I'm importing data from another repository where the ID is a primary key. For clarity, I'd prefer to have just a single ID going around. This will definitely reduce the misunderstandings such as "is it a remote-id-77 or a local-id-77?"

Answer (score 1):

To identify your entities, Doctrine must be aware of them. This step is done by the "persist" method of your entity manager when you create an entity by hand. On the other hand, if you get the entity from the database, Doctrine will already be aware of its existence.

That's why you get an error when you run this code twice. Because Doctrine will try to insert a new entity with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

persist() tells Doctrine "this is new, please insert". If you do not know, whether the entity is already in the Database, the right method is merge(). Then Doctrine checks itself.

So in your case:

```
$prop = new Property();
$prop->setId(1);
$prop->setName('baobao');
$this->em->merge($dbProperty); // <- here
$this->em->flush();
```

Comment: `merge` has been deprecated and will be removed in 3.0. He's supposed to fetch the entity through the ORM first, not to do any magic.